# re.search in Python yields "none" when using a file as the input

Tags: python

I am very new to stack overflow and to programming in general, and appreciate any help you can provide!

I want to use the re.search function in Python to find text in a file (this is just practice, because ultimately I want to use re.sub and regular expressions to find/replace). But I can't get it to work!

For example, if I enter the following code into Python:

```
import re
SearchStr = 'world'
Result = re.search(SearchStr,"Hello world")
print Result
```

I get the following output: `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106875e00>`
Great!

But then I made a file called "python_test.txt" which contains the text "Hello world", and I ran the following script:

```
import re
InFileName = 'python_test.txt'
InFile = open(InFileName, 'r')
SearchStr = 'world'
Result = re.search(SearchStr,InFile)
print Result
```

I get the following output: `None`

If I replace the last three lines with `InFile.read()`, I get `'Hello world.\n'` as the output, so I think my script is reading the file just fine. I have also tried using `InFile.read()` instead of `InFile` in my `re.search` terms; that didn't work either. Why doesn't my script find "world" in my file?

Comment: Correct, you need to read from the file first. Just opening it you are getting a file object `InFile` in your case. You need to do some kind of read to get the data from the file and then run `re.search(SearchStr, <data>)` on the gathered `<data>`

Comment: `re.search` expects a string.

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` expects string as the second argument. Not the file. Try use:

```
Result = re.search(SearchStr,InFile.read())
```